# ajax page loading, wont load pages personal CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, ipad, loading

i am creating an ipad app

i have a side navigation, and then a main window. user will click links in the navigation and pages will load up in the main window.

i use ajax to dynamically load my pages in my main window, but when my pages load they do not load with their own css or js files, which i have linked in the page html file.

instead i belive they take on the CSS of the entire site.

i have read i can use 'loadobjs' to load my CSS and my page loads dynamically.

how can i use that with my code?

a reply will be greatly appreciated

thank you

code provided below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 // load index page when the page loads
 $("#main_content_inner").load("home.html");

 $("#home").click(function(){
 // load home page on click
  $("#main_content_inner").load("home.html");

 });
 $("#latest").click(function(){
 // load contact form onclick
  $("#main_content_inner").load("latest.html");
 });
 $("#important").click(function(){
 // load contact form onclick
  $("#main_content_inner").load("important.html");

 });
 $("#personal").click(function(){
 // load contact form onclick
  $("#main_content_inner").load("personal.html");

 });
 $("#timetable").click(function(){
 // load contact form onclick
  $("#main_content_inner").load("timetable.html");

 });
 $("#tasks").click(function(){
 // load contact form onclick
  $("#main_content_inner").load("tasks.html");

 });
 $("#staff").click(function(){
 // load contact form onclick
  $("#main_content_inner").load("staff.html");

 });
 $("#university").click(function(){
 // load contact form onclick
  $("#main_content_inner").load("university.html");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but my recommendation is for the outer page's CSS to have all the necessary information for each child page you load.

Also, you **shouldn't** load entire HTML documents via AJAX; your DOM would end up looking something like this (which is **bad**)

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div id="ajax_panel">
            <html>
                <head>...</head>
                <body> Content </body>
            </html>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead, modify your inner documents to only contain the information that should be in your `div#main_content_inner`.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, initially i was just loading sections of the html into my main page(content)....but i found if i added a javascript to the section, it would not load up on my main page, with ajax. if i opened the page on its own by clicking the html file the javascript function would work, if i used the ajax to load the content that contained the javascript it would not load...which made me think it would b better to load the entire html document as opposed to just the section....any suggestions?

Comment: Just like the CSS styles, you need to have all the JavaScript available on the outer page. AJAX loading should be limited to content, not assets.